# Majorana equation and non-invariance of spinor representation under discrete Lorentz transformations

Tags: special-relativity, dirac-equation, majorana-fermions

[Here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/87123/equation-for-relativistic-electron-and-two-component-spinor) I asked about getting an equation for two-component spinor as the alternative for Dirac equation. It was found that it is called Majorana equation. It may be easily derived by using historical Dirac's method of deriving homonymous equation, but with using the requirement of the absence invariance of the Lagrangian under U(1) transformations. But in the linked question I also wrote about the absense of invariance of spinor $\left(\frac{1}{2}, 0 \right)$ representation of the Lorentz group under discrete transformations of the Lorentz group. If these symmetries is absent, why do we need to analyze this equation?

Comment: Because there exist a particle - neutrino - that violates parity.